# What is the name of cookie-like creature on git homepage logo

Tags: git, cookies, image

For years I suffered from a question of what is the name of creature, that looks like a cookie, and located at [git homepage](http://git-scm.com/) header logo. And are there any pictures of same creature? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a home-made [domokun](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=domokun).

Hmm, on second thoughts, I don't think this question will last...

Comment: It probably is off-topic, but I find myself with no desire to close it!

Comment: I especially like the illustration's allusion to "processing" trees/branches with ease.